# How to name the discrete analog of coincidence of Riemann and Lebesgue integrals?

Tags: combinatorics, education, math-history

It's known that for any sequence of positive integers $a_1$, $a_2$, ..., $a_n$ the following equality holds:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z},k\geqslant 1} \left|\{i\colon a_i\geqslant k\}\right|.
$$

I think the easiest way to understand this is to draw a set of rectangles $1\times a_1$, $1\times a_2$, ..., $1\times a_n$ and to calculate the area of all of them in two ways:

1. "Riemann style": sum their areas.
2. "Lebesgue style": calculate the number of squares $1\times 1$ in the first row ($\left|\{i\colon a_i\geqslant 1\}\right|$), add the number of squares $1\times 1$ in the second row ($\left|\{i\colon a_i\geqslant 2\}\right|$) and so on.

Do you know how this transformation is called?

It looks like the special case of Abel transformation (for large enough $N$, $f_k=\left|\{i\colon a_i\geqslant k\}\right|$, $g_k=k-1$):
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{N} \bigl(k-(k-1))\bigr)\cdot \left|\{i\colon a_i\geqslant k\}\right|=-\sum_{k=2}^N (k-1)\cdot \bigl(\left|\{i\colon a_i\geqslant k\}\right|-\left|\{i\colon a_i\geqslant k-1\}\right|\bigr)=\sum_{k=1}^{N}k\cdot \left|\{i\colon a_i=k\}\right|.
$$
But I want to believe that this fact has its own name (SomeGoodAndBigMathematician transformation)

Comment: Additionally, I want to know some beautiful results that use this fact

Comment: Also asked on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1997846_how_to_name_the_discrete_analog_of_coincidence_of_riemann_and_lebesgue_integrals

Comment: Why not some woman?

Comment: @j-w-tanner, I'm not very good at English. I changed it to "Mathematician".

Answer (score 2):

It's the *cumulative frequency distribution*.

We can convert the $a_i$ into frequencies $f_j$ from which we can create a *histogram*.
$$f_j=|\{i:a_i=j\}|$$
When we turn them into a cumulative distribution $g_k$, we get the desired sequence.
$$g_k=\sum_{j\le k} f_j = |\{i:k\le a_i\}|$$

I guess we could call it a *Pearson transform* after Karl Pearson who first introduced the histogram.
Unfortunately this transform is not invertible, which for instance the Abel transform is.
Alternatively we might call it the *discrete Lesbesgue transform*, which is the same thing.

As for beautiful results... does the entire branch of statistics count?

Comment: It's an exciting idea. But I don't think it's the proper answer. For me, it is just another view. In the same manner, we can think about it as Young tableaux...